# What to do with the error "Ambiguous Columns Defined"?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my sql command:

```
select INCOME_TYPE_ID,
       REGION_CODE,
       FIN_YEAR_CODE,
       PORTION_AMOUNT
  from INCOME.INCOME_TYPE, 
       COMMON.REGION, 
       INCOME.RECEIVE_DOC_PORTION, 
       INCOME.ASSESS_ORDER_ITEM, 
       ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM_RECEIVE_DOC, 
       ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM, 
       ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER, 
       ACCOUNTING.FIN_YEAR
 where INCOME.RECEIVE_DOC_PORTION.ASSESS_ORDER_ITEM_ID = INCOME.ASSESS_ORDER_ITEM.ASSESS_ORDER_ITEM_ID
   and INCOME.ASSESS_ORDER_ITEM.INCOME_TYPE_ID=INCOME.INCOME_TYPE.INCOME_TYPE_ID
   and INCOME.RECEIVE_DOC_PORTION.RECEIVE_DOC_PORTION_ID = ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM_RECEIVE_DOC.RECEIVE_DOC_PORTION_ID
   and ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM_RECEIVE_DOC.VOUCHER_ITEM_ID = ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM.VOUCHER_ITEM_ID
   and ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM.VOUCHER_ID = ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER.VOUCHER_ID
   and ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER.REGION_CODE = COMMON.REGION.REGION_CODE
   and ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER.FIN_YEAR_CODE = ACCOUNTING.FIN_YEAR.FIN_YEAR_CODE
```

and I got this error:

> Ambiguous Columns Defined

I'm Using SQL Developer as Oracle client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently one (or more) column names in your select list exists in more than one table of the FROM list.

You need to prefix every column in the SELECT list with the table it's coming from (it's also a good practice to always do that, regardless of the fact if they are ambigous)

Comment: curiously the OP has prefixed the column names in the join clauses, just not in the projection.

Comment: @APC: yes, I noticed that too. Seems a strange naming "habit"

Answer (score 1):

Mention name of table before every column in select query. 
Ambiguous column means that you have more than one column with the same name in one of the SELECT statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, prefgixing all selected columns with their fully qualified names (as you have done elsewhere in your `SELECT`):

```
select INCOME.INCOME_TYPE.INCOME_TYPE_ID,
       COMMON.REGION.REGION_CODE,
       ACCOUNTING.FIN_YEAR.FIN_YEAR_CODE,
       ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM_RECEIVE_DOC.PORTION_AMOUNT
  from INCOME.INCOME_TYPE, 
       COMMON.REGION, 
       INCOME.RECEIVE_DOC_PORTION, 
       INCOME.ASSESS_ORDER_ITEM, 
       ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM_RECEIVE_DOC, 
       ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM, 
       ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER, 
       ACCOUNTING.FIN_YEAR
 where INCOME.RECEIVE_DOC_PORTION.ASSESS_ORDER_ITEM_ID = INCOME.ASSESS_ORDER_ITEM.ASSESS_ORDER_ITEM_ID
   and INCOME.ASSESS_ORDER_ITEM.INCOME_TYPE_ID = INCOME.INCOME_TYPE.INCOME_TYPE_ID
   and INCOME.RECEIVE_DOC_PORTION.RECEIVE_DOC_PORTION_ID = ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM_RECEIVE_DOC.RECEIVE_DOC_PORTION_ID
   and ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM_RECEIVE_DOC.VOUCHER_ITEM_ID = ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM.VOUCHER_ITEM_ID
   and ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM.VOUCHER_ID = ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER.VOUCHER_ID
   and ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER.REGION_CODE = COMMON.REGION.REGION_CODE
   and ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER.FIN_YEAR_CODE = ACCOUNTING.FIN_YEAR.FIN_YEAR_CODE
```

I had to guess the filly qualified name for

```
ACCOUNTING.VOUCHER_ITEM_RECEIVE_DOC.PORTION_AMOUNT
```

It might be

```
INCOME.RECEIVE_DOC_PORTION.PORTION_AMOUNT
```

But you should be able to resolve that easily.

Hope it helps...